# how to foreach the array with string key

Tags: php, foreach

I have this array that the key of this, is string :

```
array
(
    [FJD] => 2.04104
    [MXN] => 20.47961
    [STD] => 20466.377105
    [SCR] => 21.203708
    [CDF] => 1975.464421
    [BBD] => 2.0
    [GTQ] => 7.770557
    [CLP] => 734.801634
)
```

How can I echo without `foreach`?

```
FJD: 2.04104
MXN: 20.47961
STD: 20466.377105
.
.
.
```

Comment: By doing the exact thing you said - `foreach` and `echo`. It's all pretty basic. Have you actually tried anything before posting the question?

Comment: Without `foreach`? You could use `for`. Without iterating at all? You can't. Unless you're satisfied with one of the formats that `var_dump`, `print_r` or `var_export` offer.

Comment: Why is your title named: `how to foreach the array with string key`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_walk` to apply a function to each member of the array if you don't want a `foreach` or `for` loop:

```
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) {
    echo $key.': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print_r($array);
```

Or:

```
var_dump($array);
```

Or:

```
var_export($array);
```

Or:
Full Credits to @cOle2:

```
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) {
    echo $key.': '.$value. "<br>";
});
```

Or, if you change your mind, you can always just use foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ': '. $value . "<br>";
}
```

Have a nice day cod3ing.